# Trying to build Sudoku board in Java Swing. NullPointerException error?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception, sudoku

I am working on building the GUI for a java program that will generate and solve sudoku puzzles. The way I am doing it is have 1 main jpanel, with 3x3 jpanels inside it, which have 3x3 jlabels in them.

Here is what I have so far:

```
package sudoku;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Gui {

    Gui gui;
    JPanel board;
    JPanel subBoard[][];
    GridLayout layout;
    JLabel square[][];
    Border big;
    Border small;

    public void load() {

        gui = new Gui();
        gui.setUp();
        gui.buildBoard();

    }

    private void setUp() {

        layout = new GridLayout(3, 3);
        board = new JPanel(layout);
        subBoard = new JPanel[3][3];
        square = new JLabel[9][9];

    }

    private void buildBoard() {

        // set up board
        board.setVisible(true);

        int mod = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                // add subBoards to board
                board.add(subBoard[i][j]);
                subBoard[i][j].setLayout(layout);

                // add textfields to each subBoard
                subBoard[i][j].add(square[i + mod][j + mod]);

            }
            mod += 3;

        }
    }

}
```

I am getting a NullPointerException error on this line:

```
board.add(subBoard[i][j]);
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? Also if you see any other problems, or just a better way I could be doing this please let me know!
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `setUp()` method at this line

```
subBoard = new JPanel[3][3];
```

you've only created the Array but have not filled it with JPanel's yet.

So, by default your Array contains `null` for every index position and hence when you try to add them to your `board` (which unlike `subBoard` was properly initialized to `new JPanel(layout)`) it throws an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sudoku {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int p = 1;
        Random r = new Random();
        int i1=r.nextInt(8);
        int firstval = i1;
        while (p == 1) {
            int x = firstval, v = 1;
            int a[][] = new int[9][9];
            int b[][] = new int[9][9];
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    if ((x + j + v) <= 9)
                        a[i][j] = j + x + v;
                    else
                        a[i][j] = j + x + v - 9;
                    if (a[i][j] == 10)
                        a[i][j] = 1;
                    // System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
                }
                x += 3;
                if (x >= 9)
                    x = x - 9;
                // System.out.println();
                if (i == 2) {
                    v = 2;
                    x = firstval;
                }
                if (i == 5) {
                    v = 3;
                    x = firstval;
                }

            }
            int eorh;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out
                    .println("hey lets play a game of sudoku:take down the question and replace the 0's with your digits and complete the game by re entering your answer");
            System.out.println("enter your option 1.hard  2.easy");
            eorh = in.nextInt();
            switch (eorh) {
            case 1:
                b[0][0] = a[0][0];
                b[8][8] = a[8][8];
                b[0][3] = a[0][3];
                b[0][4] = a[0][4];
                b[1][2] = a[1][2];
                b[1][3] = a[1][3];
                b[1][6] = a[1][6];
                b[1][7] = a[1][7];
                b[2][0] = a[2][0];
                b[2][4] = a[2][4];
                b[2][8] = a[2][8];
                b[3][2] = a[3][2];
                b[3][8] = a[3][8];
                b[4][2] = a[4][2];
                b[4][3] = a[4][3];
                b[4][5] = a[4][5];
                b[4][6] = a[4][6];
                b[5][0] = a[5][0];
                b[5][6] = a[5][6];
                b[6][0] = a[6][0];
                b[6][4] = a[6][4];
                b[6][8] = a[6][8];
                b[7][1] = a[7][1];
                b[7][2] = a[7][2];
                b[7][5] = a[7][5];
                b[7][6] = a[7][6];
                b[8][4] = a[8][4];
                b[8][5] = a[8][5];
                b[0][0] = a[0][0];
                b[8][8] = a[8][8];

                break;
            case 2:
                b[0][3] = a[0][3];
                b[0][4] = a[0][4];
                b[1][2] = a[1][2];
                b[1][3] = a[1][3];
                b[1][6] = a[1][6];
                b[1][7] = a[1][7];
                b[1][8] = a[1][8];
                b[2][0] = a[2][0];
                b[2][4] = a[2][4];
                b[2][8] = a[2][8];
                b[3][2] = a[3][2];
                b[3][5] = a[3][5];
                b[3][8] = a[3][8];
                b[4][0] = a[4][0];
                b[4][2] = a[4][2];
                b[4][3] = a[4][3];
                b[4][4] = a[4][4];
                b[4][5] = a[4][5];
                b[4][6] = a[4][6];
                b[5][0] = a[5][0];
                b[5][1] = a[5][1];
                b[5][4] = a[5][4];
                b[5][6] = a[5][6];
                b[6][0] = a[6][0];
                b[6][4] = a[6][4];
                b[6][6] = a[6][6];
                b[6][8] = a[6][8];
                b[7][0] = a[7][0];
                b[7][1] = a[7][1];
                b[7][2] = a[7][2];
                b[7][5] = a[7][5];
                b[7][6] = a[7][6];
                b[8][2] = a[8][2];
                b[8][4] = a[8][4];
                b[8][5] = a[8][5];
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("entered option is incorrect");
                break;
            }

            for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < 9; z++) {
                    System.out.print(b[y][z] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("enter your answer");
            int c[][] = new int[9][9];
            for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < 9; z++) {
                    c[y][z] = in.nextInt();
                }
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < 9; z++)
                    System.out.print(c[y][z] + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }
            int q = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < 9; z++)
                    if (a[y][z] == c[y][z])
                        continue;
                    else {
                        q++;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            if (q == 0)
                System.out
                        .println("the answer you have entered is correct well done");
            else
                System.out.println("oh  wrong answer better luck next time");
            System.out
                    .println("do you want to play a different game of sudoku(1/0)");
            p = in.nextInt();
            firstval=r.nextInt(8);
            /*if (firstval > 8)
                firstval -= 9;*/
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this code generates a Sudoku question and compares the solved Sudoku entered by the user and displays whether the entered Sudoku is correct or not.

Comment: nice code (maybe :-) - just: can't see much of a relation to the question (which is about doing so in Swing)